# Graph API authentication | The request body must contain the following parameter 'grant_type'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api

I'm trying to authenticate to Graph using Postman. I have the following request:

Type: Post
Url: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/[MyTenantIdHere]/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5BMyTenantIdHere%5D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Body = Raw:

```
{
  client_id: "[MyClientID]",
  grant_type: "client_credentials",
  scope: "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default",
  client_secret: "[MyClientSecret"
}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the
> following parameter: 'grant_type'.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: can you please try with curl `curl -X POST -d “grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=clientid&client_secret=secret&scope= https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default” https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token` and let us know if it helps.

Comment: It works with this format, I guess it doesn't accept JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try X-www-form-urlencoded in postman.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you choose "raw" and put it there in this form:

```
client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```